# JQuery filtering Gallery

Tags: jquery

i have created a filtered gallery and its working nice but i have one confliction that i want not to fade out (disappear) pictures of the un selcted categories i just want to decrease its opacity and show the selected category with its full opacity... i tried to replace `fadeout()` function with `fadeTo()` function but it didn't work .... here below the code that i created for this html page.... i have no any problem with the code except this point but it works great.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  jQuery(function($) {

    // filter selector
    $("#galleryTab a").on("click", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      // if we click the active tab, do nothing
      if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
        $("#galleryTab a").removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass("active"); // set the active tab
        // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
        var $filter = $this.data("rel");
        // if we select view all, return to initial settings and show all
        $filter == 'all' ?
          $(".fancybox")
          .attr("data-fancybox-filter", "fancybox")
          .not(":visible")
          .fadeIn() : // otherwise
          $(".fancybox")
          .fadeOut()
          .filter(function() {
            // set data-filter value as the data-rel value of selected tab
            return $(this).data("filter") == $filter;
          })
          // set data-fancybox-filter and show filtered elements
          .attr("data-fancybox-filter", "$filter")
          .fadeIn();

      } // if
    }); // on
    // fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      modal: false, // enable regular nav and close buttons
      // add buttons helper (requires buttons helper js and css files)
      padding: 0,
      helpers: {
        thumbs: {
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        },
      }
    });

  }); // ready

<
/script>
```

```html
<div id="galleryTab">
  <a data-rel="all" href="javascript:;" class="filter active">All Projects</a>
  <a data-rel="vil" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Villas</a>
  <a data-rel="res" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Residential and Commercial</a>
  <a data-rel="mix" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Mixed Used</a>
  <a data-rel="port" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Previous Projects</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="galleryWrap" class="cf">


    <!-- villas -->
    <a title="Mr.Omran Villa (G+1+R)" class="fancybox" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/1s.jpg" alt="omran" width="240" height="160" id="img1"></a>
    <div class="hidden">
      <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/1h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/1h.jpg" alt="omran"></a>
      <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/12h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/12h.jpg" alt="omran"></a>
    </div>


    <a title="Mr.saif Villa (G+1+R)" data-tags="Villas" class="fancybox" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/2s.jpg" alt="saif" width="240" height="159" class="img-responsive" id="img2"></a>
    <div class="hidden">
      <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/21h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/21h.jpg" alt="saif"></a>
      <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/22h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/22h.jpg" alt="saif"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Buildings -->
    <a title="Ajman Tower (G+8Podium+26 Typical+R)" class="fancybox" data-tags="Residential and Commercial" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/4.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/4s.jpg" alt="ajman" width="240" height="160" class="img-responsive" border="0"></a>
    <div class="hidden">
      <a class="fancybox" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/41h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/41h.jpg" alt="ajman"></a>
      <a class="fancybox" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/42h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/42h.jpg" alt="ajman"></a>
    </div>
```